# Django can't add new item to another database on admin site

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, django

I'm using two databases to create an app and everything looks fine, I can change, delete the existing item but can't add new item to other database table on the admin site. The data should be stored in `dbcost.tbItemDetail` instead of `userauth.tbItemDetail`. Does anyone know how to correct this?
Thanks

Here is the code:
code on admin.py:

```
from unicodedata import name
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

#Create MultiDBModelAdmin to expose multiple databases for admin site
class MultiDBModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin): 
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
         # Tell Django to save objects to the other database.
        obj.save(using=self.using)
        
    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        # Tell Django to delete objects from the other database
        obj.delete(using=self.using)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Tell Django to look for objects on the other database.
        return super().get_queryset(request).using(self.using)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ForeignKey widgets using a query
        # on the other database.
        return super().formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ManyToMany widgets using a query
        # on the other database.
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, using=self.using, **kwargs)
# Register your other database here:
class tb_companyinfo(MultiDBModelAdmin):
    using = 'dbcost' #select database name    
    list_display = ('name','emailaddress',) #add different fields into admin site

class tb_itemdetail(MultiDBModelAdmin):
    using = 'dbcost' #select database name    
    list_display = ('sku','item_name',) #add different fields into admin site 

#class tb_invoice(MultiDBModelAdmin):
    #using = 'dbcost' #select database name    
    #list_display = ('companyid','invoicedate',) #add different fields into admin site 

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(companyinfo, tb_companyinfo)
admin.site.register(itemdetail, tb_itemdetail)
#admin.site.register(invoice, tb_invoice)
```

mode.py:

```
from django.db import models
class companyinfo(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True, max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.
    name = models.CharField(db_column='Name', max_length=200)  # Field name made lowercase.
    address1 = models.CharField(db_column='Address1', max_length=200)  # Field name made lowercase.
    address2 = models.CharField(db_column='Address2', max_length=200)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phonenumber = models.CharField(db_column='PhoneNumber', max_length=100, verbose_name='Phone Number')  # Field name made lowercase.
    emailaddress = models.CharField(db_column='EmailAddress', max_length=100, verbose_name='Email Address')  # Field name made lowercase.
    country = models.CharField(db_column='Country', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:        
        verbose_name_plural = 'Company Info' #show the name as 'Company Info' in admin instead of companyinfo
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbCompanyInfo'
class invoice(models.Model):
    id = models.OneToOneField('itemInvoice', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    companyid = models.ForeignKey(companyinfo, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='Company ID')  # Field name made lowercase.
    invoicedate = models.DateField(db_column='InvoiceDate')  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Invoice'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbInvoice'


class itemdetail(models.Model):
    sku = models.CharField(db_column='SKU', primary_key=True, max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    item_name = models.CharField(db_column='Item Name', max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase. Field renamed to remove unsuitable characters.
    shortdescription = models.TextField(db_column='ShortDescription', verbose_name='Short Description')  # Field name made lowercase.
    detaildescription = models.TextField(db_column='DetailDescription', verbose_name='Detail Description')  # Field name made lowercase.
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Product Details'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbItemDetail'


class itemInvoice(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    invoice_no = models.CharField(db_column='Invoice_No', max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    sku = models.ForeignKey(itemdetail, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='SKU')  # Field name made lowercase.
    quantity = models.IntegerField(db_column='Quantity')  # Field name made lowercase.
    cost = models.DecimalField(db_column='Cost', max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Invoicing Items'
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbItem_Invoice'
```

database in setting.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'userauth',
        'USER':'sql-conn',
        'HOST':'myhosting',
        'PORT':3307,
        'PASSWORD':'mypassword',
    },

    'dbcost': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'dbCosts',
        'USER':'sql-conn',
        'HOST':'myhosting',
        'PORT':3307,
        'PASSWORD':'mypassword',
    }
}
```

The error show up when I filled the form and hit save to add the new item on admin site:
[error showed when hit save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QA2Ti.png)

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/invoicing/itemdetail/add/
(1146, "Table 'userauth.tbItemDetail' doesn't exist")
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/invoicing/itemdetail/add/
Django Version: 4.1
Exception Type: ProgrammingError
Exception Value:    
(1146, "Table 'userauth.tbItemDetail' doesn't exist")
Exception Location: C:\Python\.venv\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py, line 254, in query
Raised during:  django.contrib.admin.options.add_view
Python Executable:  C:\Python\.venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.10.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Python\\costcalculate\\apps',
 'C:\\Python\\costcalculate',
 'C:\\Users\\VM1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\python310.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\VM1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\VM1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\VM1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310',
 'C:\\Python\\.venv',
 'C:\\Python\\.venv\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Wed, 24 Aug 2022 02:24:14 -0700
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Database Router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/#database-routers) to force writing in the right db.

```
class CustomDbRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model == itemdetail:
            return "dbcost"
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model == itemdetail:
            return "dbcost"
        return None
```

add in settings.py

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["app_name.CustomDbRouter"]
```

Comment: Hi, after added your code, the app can save now but no data is showed anywhere...

Comment: Can you explain where was te data before?

Comment: They were in dbcost database

Comment: Hi, your code worked! Thank you so much!